# Custom URL Rewriting with parametres

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show.php?cat=rc&id=573
```

I want the below result

```
localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/rc/573
```

My `.htaccess` code is (but not working)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule show/cat/(.*)/id/(.*)/ show.php?cat=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule show/cat/(.*)/id/(.*) show.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

Mode_rewrite is on and also checked for redirecting a website and it is perfectly working

Comment: You need to provide more information in order for us to give you a useful answer. You say it's not working, but what is the behavior you're seeing? When you say you "want the below result", you mean that's the URL you want your visitor to enter, or that's the URL you want it to be rewritten to?

Comment: localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show.php?cat=rc&id=573 this is the dynamic url(actual URL) i want to redirect this type of URls to the below url.
localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/rc/573

Comment: Ok. You're actually getting the terminology backwards, though. The URL that the user enters is the thing that gets "redirected", or actually just rewritten in this case. An unambiguous way to say it is that you want requests made to `localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/rc/573` to be reserved by `localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show.php?cat=rc&id=573`.

Comment: Want this localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/rc/573 instead of localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show.php?cat=rc&id=573 (and this is the actual URl)

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I can see that the result you want is missing the "cat" parameter. The other thing I notice is that `.*` is usually greedy quantifier: it will consume everything, so nothing after it will match. I don't remember offhand exactly what Apache's regex flavor does, but I would guess you need to either qualify the characters to match, or make the quantifier reluctant. The first way might look like this:

```
RewriteRule show/cat/([^\/]*)/id/([^\/]*)/ show.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

And the second would look like:

```
RewriteRule show/cat/(.*?)/id/(.*?)/ show.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

However, I hope you realize that the URL you gave, `localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/rc/573`, doesn't match this pattern: it's missing the `"cat"` and `"id"` string. For it to match, you would need something like:

```
localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/cat/rc/id/573/
```

Also, it is usually a good idea to anchor your rewrite rules, so they don't get applied unexpectedly. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/cat/([^\/]*)/id/([^\/]*)/ show.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

(assuming `"localhost"` is the domain name, and not part of the path).

Comment: Not woking What to do .

Comment: This i want in Custom PHP site

Comment: The easiest way to debug rewrite rules is to turn on logging. In httpd version 2.2, for instance, you can use `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` directives to setup debug logging of the rewrite engine. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog for more information.

Comment: If you still can't get it working, you need to provide more details. Imagine if I approached you and said "My car doesn't work, how do I fix it?" Even if you know all there is to know about cars, this doesn't give you any information about what might be wrong. This is essentially the position you have put us in. If you want help, you need to tell us things like: what URL did you try to access, what was the result that was served up, what did your server log say, what did the rewrite log say, where is the .htaccess file? The more information you provide, the more likely someone can help you.

Comment: For get the above from start i have :  http://localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show.php?id=573&cat=rc

Comment: Want to rewrite this(above) url to http://localhost/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/573/rc

Comment: I use this to check rewrite mode in wamp server Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com/? [L,R]  It is working fine

Comment: .htaccess is placed in " Play " (folder)

Comment: RewriteRule ^/sdpisdtv2014/play/show/id/([^\/]*)/cat/([^\/]*)/ show.php?id=$1&cat=$2  Not working

Comment: I am waiting for your response

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions. I already offered everything I know about it and told you how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule show/cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ show.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

this should work

Comment: This is also Not Working